# Как скрыть от программы strings наличие Python кода в собранном pyinstaller-ом .exe файле?

Tags: python, exe, pyinstaller

Если пропустить через встроенную утилиту *strings* собранный .exe файл c помощью *pyinstaller*, которая в Linux , то *strings* выдаст модули использованные в программе или просто будет упомянут сам Python таким образом:

```
Cannot GetProcAddress for PyErr_Clear
PyErr_Occurred
Cannot GetProcAddress for PyErr_Occurred
PyErr_Print
Cannot GetProcAddress for PyErr_Print
PyImport_AddModule
Cannot GetProcAddress for PyImport_AddModule
PyImport_ExecCodeModule
Cannot GetProcAddress for PyImport_ExecCodeModule
PyImport_ImportModule
Cannot GetProcAddress for PyImport_ImportModule
PyList_Append
Cannot GetProcAddress for PyList_Append
...
```

Могут ли такое обойти и как ?

Comment: нужно обфусцировать код

Comment: Явно скомпилировать python-код **невозможно**. Потому что это интерпретируемый язык программирования. Но можно воспользоваться некоторыми проектами "недо-python". Например Cython(по сути мост между Си и python), PyPy(на сколько я знаю, у них имеется динамическая предкомпиляция)